# How to implement a robust Ancova with more than 2 groups in R

Tags: r, anova, ancova, robust

It seems to me that all the robust ancova functions in the Wrs2 package in R work only with two groups ( two levels of the VI factor).

In case the factor has more than 2 levels how can a user apply a robust ancova?

Does any other formula with more than two groups or something else exist?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, WRS2 has only a some of the robust functions. If you use WRS there will be many more available.

To do so

```
# first: install dependent packages
install.packages(c("MASS", "akima", "robustbase"))

# second: install suggested packages
install.packages(c("cobs", "robust", "mgcv", "scatterplot3d", "quantreg", "rrcov", "lars", "pwr", "trimcluster", "parallel", "mc2d", "psych", "Rfit"))

# third: install WRS
install.packages("WRS", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type="source")
```

Then use the function `bwwtrim` (if you have 1 between factor and 2 within), `bbw` (2 between and 1 within) or either `bbbtrim`/`wwwtrim` (if you have 3 between or 2 within factors).

Good Luck!